Question about an exercise on monomial order.
Background
Definition 1  We will introduce an order relation $\prec$ on $\mathfrak{M}$.  We define $\prec$ to be an admissible order relation on $\mathfrak{M}$ if it is a total order which is compatible with the multiplication of monomials, i.e.,
$(1)$ For any paire of monomials $m,n$ we have $m\prec n$ or $n\prec m$ or $m=n$
$(2)$ if $m_1\prec m_2$ and $m_2\prec m_3$ then $m_1\prec m_3$
$(3)$ $1\prec m$ for any monomial $m\neq 1$
$(4)$ if $m_1\prec m_2$ then $mm_1\prec mm_2$ for any monomial $m$
Definition 2  The degree reverse lexicographic ordering, $\text{Degrevlex.}$  Here $m=x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}\prec x_1^{j_1}\cdots x_n^{j_n}=n$ if $\text{deg }m< \text{deg }n$ or $\text{deg }m = \text{deg }n$ and $i_n=j_n, i_{n-1}=j_{n-1},\ldots, i_k=j_k, i_{k-1}>j_{k-1}$ for some $k$.  In other words $m\prec n$ if $\text{deg }m< \text{deg }n$ or $\text{deg }m = \text{deg }n$ and the last variable with different exponents in $m$ and $n$ has higher exponent in $m$.
Exercise show that $x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}\prec x_1^{j_1}\cdots x_n^{j_n}$ if $i_n=j_n, i_{n-1}=j_{n-1},\ldots, i_k=j_k, i_{k-1}>j_{k-1}$ for some $k$, does not define an admissible ordering.
Questions
For the above quoted Exercise, i am not sure why the particular ordering is not an admissible ordering. I tried letting $k=1$, but then that would mean $x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}= x_1^{j_1}\cdots x_n^{j_n}$ which satisifies $(1)$ in Definition 1, but it violates Definition 2.  I am not sure if that is what the exercise is looking for in terms of solution.
Thank you in advance

I am not sure but if I understand your exercise correctly then $x \prec 1$ which violates trichotomy.

@Marc-AndréBrochu how does the condition in the exercise mean $x\prec 1$?

Well $x_1^1 \prec x_1^0$ according to your definition.

@Marc-AndréBrochu oh right.  for some reasons, I read the inequality backwards.  Can I trouble you with this recent post. Is related to condition $(3)$ of the Definition 1 of this post.  I  am having trouble understanding why that condition is there.  thank you in advance.
